# A question about entire function without zeros bounded by expontential

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help to solve the following problem, thank you in advance. Let $M,a_+ \in \mathbb R$ such that $M,a_+>0$. Suppose $f$ is entire,
$$f(z) \neq 0 \ \ \forall z \in \mathbb C,$$
$$|f(z)| \leq M e^{a_+|Im(z)|} \quad \forall z \in \{z \in \mathbb C \mid Im(z) \leq 0 \}, \quad and$$
$$|f(z)| \leq M \quad \forall z \in \{z \in \mathbb C \mid Im(z) \geq 0 \},$$
then $f(z)=Ce^{iaz}$ where $0 \leq a \leq a_+$.

Comment: If a entire function $f$ satisfies $f(z)\neq0$ for every $z$ then there is $g$ an entire function such that $f(z)=e^{g(z)}$, you can proof this using that the 1-form $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$ is closed so it's exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(z) \ne 0$ means $\log f=g$ is analytic so $f(z)=e^{g(z)}, |f(z)|=e^{\Re g(z)}$

So we get $\Re g \le \log M, \Im z \ge 0$ and $\Re g \le \log M+a_+|\Im z|, \Im z \le 0$

Since $M,M+a_+|\Im z| \le M+a_+|z|$ we get that

$\Re g(z) \le M+a_+|z|, z \in \mathbb C$,

which by Borel Caratheodory applied to the circles $|z|=R, |z|=2R$ gives

$\max_{|z|=R}|g(z)| \le 4a_+R+M_1, M_1 >0$,

or $|g(z)| \le 4a_+|z|+M_1, z \in \mathbb C$,

which means g(z)=$cz+b$ for some $c,b \in  \mathbb C$

But now taking real parts we get $u(z)=\Re c \Re z -\Im c \Im z+\Re b$ so fixing $z=x \in \mathbb R$ implies $\Re c =0$ while taking $z=ix$ implies $\Im c \ge 0$ since $u(ix) \le M$. Hence $c=ia, a \ge 0$ and now using the inequality on $\Im z \le 0$ it immediately follows $a \le a_+$ by taking $z=-ix, 0<x \to \infty$ and using $ax+\Re b \le a_+x$.

Hence $g(z)=iaz+b, f(z)=e^be^{iaz}=Ce^{iaz}, 0 \le a\le a_+$ Done!

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: happy to be of help